What is the difference between herbeiführen and verursachen in the sense of to cause?
If something caused a change for example,the food shortages cause the dissatisfaction in the population.
Is the correct verb to use verursachen or herbeiführen or can either verb be used. If that is the case then what is the difference between the verbs?

To me, "herbeiführen" implies an intention and someone who takes action to that effect, while "verursachen" has a wider meaning to cause something.
For example, if rain causes a flood, "verursachen" would fit, but not "herbeiführen".
In your example of the food shortages, "herbeiführen" could be used if someone created the food shortage with the intention that the population is dissatisfied. If the food shortage is caused by bad weather, then "verursachen" is better.
Side note: "Führt zu" can also be used for a generic cause. It is similar, but different from "herbeiführen".

As the part "führen" (to lead, to direct) in "herbeiführen" shows, that verb indicates active steering, whereas "die Ursache" (the cause) and "verursachen" imply mere cause and effect implied by nature or effects of the market. And, as already said above, steering implies a sort of free will. In judicial terms there is "mutwillig herbeiführen" to imply that the actor may be judged for the act.
